# function to find the division of 2 numbers contained in an array

Tags: javascript, algorithm, function

I am creating a function to calculate the division of 2 numbers that are inside an array. The problem I have is that the division is done the other way around. ej: if I put 10/2 as parameters, the result that returns is 2/10. So how could I solve this error?

Here I leave the complete code, just check the code of the function "fDividir".

Code javascript:

```js
sysc es un sistema que podrás usar para implementar para la creación de tu calculadora.

// inicio de las funciones

    //función sumar
    const fSumar = function (valores = "0"){
        let arregloNum = valores.split("+");
        let oSuma = 0;
        for (let i = 0; i < arregloNum.length; i++){
            oSuma = parseInt(arregloNum[i]) + oSuma;
        }
        return oSuma;
    }
    
    //función restar
    const fRestar = function (valores = "0"){
        let arregloNum = valores.split("-");
        let oResta = 0;
        for (let i = 0; i < arregloNum.length; i++){
            oResta = parseInt(arregloNum[i]) - oResta;
        }
        return oResta;
    }
    
    // función multiplicar
    const fMultiplicar = function (valores = "0"){
        let arregloNum = valores.split("×");
        let oMultiplicacion = 1;
        for (let i = 0; i < arregloNum.length; i++){
            oMultiplicacion = parseInt(arregloNum[i]) * oMultiplicacion;
        }
        return oMultiplicacion;
    }
    
    // función dividir
    const fDividir = function (valores = "0"){
        let arregloNum = valores.split("/");
        let oDivision = 1;
        for (let i = 0; i < arregloNum.length; i++){
            oDivision = parseInt(arregloNum[i]) / oDivision;
        }
        return oDivision;
    }

// fin de las funciones

console.log(fDividir("10/2")); // 0.2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another, possible solution:

```
// función dividir
    const fDividir = function (valores = "0"){
        let arregloNum = valores.split("/");
        let oDivision = arregloNum[0];
        for (let i = 1; i < arregloNum.length; i++){
            oDivision /= parseInt(arregloNum[i]);
        }
        return oDivision;
    }
```

Comment: hey take this as a compliment, "You're a genius", "You're a crack".

Comment: Thanks, you'll be a crack also with more practice...

Answer (score 1):

Change your division function:

```
// función dividir
    const fDividir = function (valores = "0"){
        let arregloNum = valores.split("/");
        let oDivision = 1;
        for (let i = arregloNum.length - 1; i > 0; i--){
            oDivision = parseInt(arregloNum[i]) * oDivision;
        }
        return arregloNum[0] / oDivision;
    }
```

Note that you were inverting the divisors order...

Comment: Hey, sorry for the inconvenience, assuming I want it to do the division with the numbers that the user needs ej: 10/2/2 = 2.5. What should I do, or what do you recommend?

Comment: I already accepted the answer

Comment: I think what you're doing is OK as you're dividing from back to front. It's efficient enough...

Comment: I think it's not right. If you take a calculator and enter 10 ÷ 2 ÷ 2 it will give you 2.5, on the other hand if we enter 10 ÷ 2 ÷ 2 in the parameters of the function you will see that it gives you 0.1 and that is a wrong value since what it would be doing is 2 ÷ 2 ÷ 10. We can get in touch for a moment perhaps in another social network easier to communicate and solve this problem. If you want you can write to my WhatsApp 3107286811.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I'll double-check the code...

Comment: Try now. The way to get it is by multiplying the divisors and dividing the first number in the chain in the last step...

Comment: I don't understand the part where they try to explain how to fix it. Could you give an example to understand it better.

Comment: I mean that if you are dividing 10/2/2 it is the same to multiply 2*2=4 and dividing 10/4=2.5 in the last step. It is the same to divide 10/2=5 and 5/2=2.5.